# I cant scale a Virtual Object in an other Class swift

Tags: swift, resize, nodes, scenekit

Im trying to figure out how to scale a Virtual object in an other class

 I tried to make a function in the extension of the Virtual object that looks like this

```
public func setSize1(_ size: Float, node: SCNNode) -> VirtualObject? {
    if let virtualObjectRoot = node as? VirtualObject {
        return virtualObjectRoot

    }
    guard let parent = node.parent else { return nil }
    node.scale = SCNVector3(x: size, y: size, z: size)
    node.position.y = (0)

    return VirtualObject.existingObjectContainingNode(parent)
}
```

And then i call it with

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let newValue = Float(sender.value)
        VirtualObject().setSize1(newValue, node: SCNNode)

    }
```

But every time i do this, i get an error like: "Cannot convert value of type 'SCNNode.Type' to expected argument type 'SCNNode'" 
 What is the best way to edit a Node in a other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
VirtualObject().setSize1(newValue, node: SCNNode)
```

You're not passing an object, but a type (*SCNNode* is the name of a class). You have to pass the *SCNNode* instance instead.

**Edit**
To retrieve the node that you want to use:

```
guard let node = self.childNode(withName: myCachedNodeName, recursively: true) else { return }
VirtualObject().setSize1(newValue, node: node)
```

**Edit 2**
Given your needs, I suggest to scale the node using a pinch gesture recognizer. This is how to add it to your scene view controller:

```
let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinch(:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)
```

Then you have to declare a method that will be executed whenever a pinch gesture is detected:

```
func pinch(gesture:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    let scale = gesture.scale
    if gesture.state == .ended {
        // Use the scale value to scale you SCNNode
        // Alternatively, you could scale your node continuously and not
        // only when the gesture is ended. But in this case, remember to
        // reset the pinch gesture recognizer's scale value
    }
}
```

Comment: You only know it. Which node do you want to scale?

Comment: It is a node chosen by the user. dont know how to get it in the class

Comment: How does the user choose it?

Comment: In a selection menu, also in an other class.

Comment: Of the whole project?

Comment: @NordyVlasman your function is in the VirtualObject class, which inherits from SCNReferenceNode. So as you said, the user chooses which node he wants to scale. How is this node named and is it a child of the VirtualObject instance?

Comment: The node is named when the user downloads it. I can get that name with caching. It is a child of the VirtualObject instance

Comment: @NordyVlasman You can retrieve the node by knowing its name. Check my edit.

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you so much

Comment: Welp, i now get an error like: Value of type 'settingsViewController' has no member 'childNode'. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Because you're calling the *setSize1* method from inside the view controller. You should call it directly from the *VirtualObject* instance that you want to scale. What are you trying to achieve and why are you trying to scale a node from inside a settings view controller?

Comment: I want to scale the virtualobject and i do that in the settingsViewController beceause there is the slider.

Comment: But is the view controller containing the SceneKit scene on screen while the user accesses the settings view controller?

Comment: No, so you say i have to do this same thing in the viewcontroller where i have the SceneKit controller?

Comment: You have two options: (1) do it in the scene view controller (have you considered using a pan gesture recognizer to scale your node instead of a slider?), (2) do it in your settings view controller and save the scale value so that you can reuse it later in your scene view controller. This depends on what you need to do in your application.

Comment: I currently thinking about using my volume up/down buttons to resize. That can be done in the scene view controller. Do i have to use the same technique for that?

Comment: I suggeat to use a pinch gesture instead.

Comment: Will do,  do you have to use some special code for that? for the other gesture handlers i used Objc

Comment: @NordyVlasman Ok, I added a sample code that shows how to use gesture recognizers in Swift. You tagged your question with the Swift tag, but are you using Objective-C instead? I'll edit the code if this is the case.

Comment: The other gestures are made in Objective-C. but this is much better to use. Thank you very much for your time!  it is working beautiful right now!